# Ubuntu 17.10: How to disable Login History

Tags: users

How do i disable the logging of my logins under Ubunutu 17.10? And are the logs just for one Week like shown in the "Settings" -» "Details" -» "Users" -» "Last Login" and are older entrys overwritten?

I don't want somewhere to be a log of my logins over the last month.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why would you like to disable Ubuntu login history?

Comment: the first rule about privacy is: do not store the data anyway. a exact protocol of logins over the last month (if there is) brings some dangers. little example: law enforcement took the pc and the data shows the times fit to useraccount XY in a board of interest / to a blog-comment written like "now we can prove that the pc was turend on at that minute" / "who downloaded this torrent at this time over the wifi we know" / etc.